# Unwanted line endings when calling file()

Tags: php, arrays, file, line-endings

I'm trying to merge array elements imported from a multi-line text file, separated by commas:

```
$ cat input.txt 
one,two,three,four
red,blue,green
human,klingon,dolphin
```

What I want to get is a single array with 10 items in it.  The code I've tried is this:

```
<?php

$fa=file("input.txt");
$w=array();
foreach($fa as $combo) {
    $w=array_merge($w,explode(",",$combo));
}
print_r($w);

?>
```

The problem is, I seem to be getting returns after line endings:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four

    [4] => red
    [5] => blue
    [6] => green

    [7] => human
    [8] => klingon
    [9] => dolphin

)
```

Why are the spaces there?  How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not spaces, they're newlines (`\n`).

Everything in the input file is represented in your array, it's just split into array elements.  The `file()` function parses your file line-by-line, and each line pulled in by `file()` includes a character that ends the line.

It sounds like you want to [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) off the whitespace.  Note that this has the added benefit of removing trailing spaces and tabs.

```
    $w=array_merge($w,explode(",",trim($combo)));
```

Does that give the results you want?

Answer (score 3):

Add a `trim()` before you insert to array to *trim* away white space characters from the start and end of a string.

For your case, you'll have to save at a temporary variable first:

```
$words = explode(',', $combo);

// Trim away white spaces for each words
$words = array_map('trim', $words);

// Now they're trimmed, array_merge them
$w = array_merge($w, $words);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to your [`file()`](http://php.net/file) call.

```
$fa=file("input.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```